# my linear model output in R isn't showing all the variables i put into it?

Tags: r

i ran a multiple regression model in r, with variables that had multiple levels. in the output, the summary shows results for every level of the two variables apart from one! i'm confused about why it isn't showing all of them?

for example, the model involved looking at an outcome (a score on a quiz) and the predictors were drunk (yes - no) and 'experience' (low - medium - high). in the output, it returns an coefficients row for every level of these factor variables apart from 'high experience'.

i am using the standard lm() structure, of lm(score ~ 1 + drink + experience + controls, data=data).
can anyone help with this??? thanks

Comment: Your ourput is almost certainly correct.  Your model is saturated, meaning that at least one factor level (here, high experience) is a linear combination of the other factor levels.  This leads to a loss of one degree of freedom.  (In fact, *any* of the factor levels could be aliased out in this way, R just chooses "experience high" because it's the "last" factor level in your model.)  A longer discussion of what's happening here is probably better suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: maybe your question is related to this one over https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27957/why-do-we-need-to-discard-one-dummy-variable. basically, one category will always be dropped in a linear model with a constant. This is called the reference category and the results of the other categories are interpreted by comparing to the reference category. As Limey said, a deeper discussion is better suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the regression coefficients to be uniquely identifiable the columns of the model matrix must be linearly independent.  Suppose we had

```
y <- 1:4
x <- factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
fm <- lm(y ~ x)
```

x has two levels but if there were a column for both they would look like this in the model matrix:

```
1 0
1 0
0 1
0 1
```

but in that case if we sum the two columns we get a vector of four 1's

```
c(1, 1, 0, 0) + c(0, 0, 1, 1)
## [1] 1 1 1 1
```

which is the same as the intercept column in the model matrix so we can't have the intercept and two columns for x at the same time.  We can either get rid of the intercept or we can only use one of the levels of x and since we have specified an intercept R drops the "a" level.

We can use `dummy.coef` to get pseudo coefficients for all levels.

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x)

coef(fm)
## (Intercept)          xb 
##         1.5         2.0 

dummy.coef(fm)
## Full coefficients are 
##                 
## (Intercept):    1.5  
## x:                a b
##                   0 2
```

Looking at the model matrix will often help understanding. The model matrix that R actually uses is the following 4x2 matrix where we see that it dropped the a level of x:

```
model.matrix(lm(y ~ x))
##   (Intercept) xb
## 1           1  0
## 2           1  0
## 3           1  1
## 4           1  1
## attr(,"assign")
## [1] 0 1
## attr(,"contrasts")
## attr(,"contrasts")$x
## [1] "contr.treatment"
```

or if we removed the intercept then it would use this 4x2 matrix:

```
model.matrix(lm(y ~ x - 1))
##   xa xb
## 1  1  0
## 2  1  0
## 3  0  1
## 4  0  1
## attr(,"assign")
## [1] 1 1
## attr(,"contrasts")
## attr(,"contrasts")$x
## [1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a statistical question, not necessarily a coding one.

When placing categorical variables in a linear model, what you actually do is create dummie for each level that indicates whether or not an observation had that specific level. For example, a factor variable of gender would be turned into a dummie for male and another for female:

[image]

(For a model with 5 observations). The problem is that, if you have an intercept in your model - and for it to be calculated we create a "variable" of 1's: [image] - the matrix of your variables will be "saturated" (as @Limey pointed out). This means that you can use [image: Xmale] and [image: Xfemale] to get [image: Xintercept] (they aren't linear independents), so your X matrix won't be reversible and you won't be able to calculate the coefficients estimates.

So to correct this you must remove [image: Xmale], or [image: Xfemale] or [image: Xintercept], and R by default removes the last factor variable (which by default is ordered alphabetically), so that's what happented with your code. We can remove one of those 3 because:

If we remove [image: Xintercept], then we will interpret the coefficient associated with
[image: Xmale] and [image: Xfemale] as "the intercept for the males" and "the intercept for the females". If we remove one of the other two, lets say [image: Xfemale], we the coefficient associated with [image: Xintercept] ais still the general intercept, and the one of [image: Xmale] will be "the difference between the female and male intercepts". This latter interpretation is easier to see if you write down the model.

The point is that even as you can't calculate one coefficient for each level, you can still get the effects that you're looking for if you know that you need to interpret the numbers as i explained in the above paragraph.

If you have more statistical questions, use Cross Validated instead :).